# Normalizing a phone number given a country code

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I have a phone number and an [ISO country code](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements-temp.htm) associated with it. For example, CA for Canada, US for the United States, GB for the UK.

The phone number may contain more than just an area code and your phone's number.

`libphonenumber` provides functions for determining whether a phone number is valid, given a country code, so I figured there should be a way to normalize it as well.

Does the library provide a way for me to convert this into an object that will properly separate dialing codes, area codes, and the phone number itself? eg: given a UK phone number of the form `+44 20 xxxx xxxx`, I want it to separate the `44` from the `20` and the `xxxx xxxx`

I see some normalization methods but they simply remove characters like hyphens, parentheses, and spaces.

Comment: over the years - i have given up on this particular idea.  now i just store the whole number - figuring what good is the separation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) PhoneNumberUtil format method will do what you want.

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Produces "044 668 18 00"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, 
    PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
```

Comment: +1. minor points to compile: you should have a semi-colon at the end of the first line and it's e.printStackTrace().  You'd also need the System.out within the scope of the variable for this to compile